# PHP curl POST token in variable

Tags: php

I can't figure out how to store some data in a variable and put it in the request header.

```
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https:url_for_request',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{"_cloudId": 99999}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Authorization: User {token}'
  ),
));
```

I need to have the token in the `$token` variable but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Do you mean you already have the token in the `$token` variable, and you want to now put that token in the Authorization header?

Comment: If you have the token in the variable `$token`, then you can either use concatenation: `'Authorization: User ' . $token` or you can use string interpolation: (requires the string to be inside double quotes): `"Authorization: User {$token}"`. You can read more about strings here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Storing data in variables is pretty basic use of PHP, did you take a tutorial or so?